# Appfabric Get List Objects In Region very slow

Tags: sql-server, performance, caching, appfabric

I use the following code to add each province item to Appfabric cache.

And use GetObjectsInRegion method to get Province list from cache.

But it is very slower than SQL server for 120 records.

With Appfabric It take over 3000 milliseconds & with SQL server around 30 milliseconds.

What is reason?

Please help me!!!!

```
try
        {
            using (CacheEntities context = new CacheEntities())
            {
                if (force)
                {
                    Cache.RemoveRegion(ObjectName);
                }
                if (Cache.CreateRegion(ObjectName))
                {
                    List<Province> province = (from t in context.Province select t).ToList<Province>();
                    if (province != null && province.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (Province provinceItem in province)
                        {
                            CommonFunctions.Add(ObjectName, provinceItem.ProvinceID, provinceItem);
                            totalItemsCached++;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            CommonFunctions.ErrorInfo(ObjectName, ex);
        }
```

Edit: cache retrieval code from comment:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Sample
{
    public List<object> GetListObjectsInRegion(string region)
    {
        var cache = GetCache();
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> rawResult = 
              cache.GetObjectsInRegion(region);

        List<object> result = new List<object>();
        Parallel.ForEach(rawResult, rawResultItem => 
              { result.Add(rawResultItem.Value); });
        return result;
    }
}
```

Update: This is code in GetCache function

```
private static DataCacheFactory _factory;
    private static DataCache _cache;
    private static DataCache GetCache()
    {
        if (_cache != null) return _cache;

        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration configuration = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();
        configuration.IsCompressionEnabled = true;
        _factory = new DataCacheFactory(configuration);
        _cache = _factory.GetCache("default");
        return _cache;
    }
```

Update: This is appfabric config

```
  </configSections>
  <dataCacheClient>
    <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="TimeoutBased" objectCount="1000" ttlValue="600" />
    <hosts>
      <host name="localhost" cachePort="22233" />
    </hosts>
  </dataCacheClient>
```

Comment: Can you post the code that retrieves the values from the cache?

Comment: public System.Collections.Generic.List<object> GetListObjectsInRegion(string region)
        {
            var cache = GetCache();
            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> rawResult = cache.GetObjectsInRegion(region);
            List<object> result = new List<object>();
            Parallel.ForEach(rawResult, rawResultItem =>
            {
                result.Add(rawResultItem.Value);
            });
            return result;
        }

Comment: Are you creating a `DataCacheFactory` in `GetCache()`? That would slow things down.

Comment: Does the code run slowly every time you run it, or is it just the first time? IE if you run your retrieval code three times without releasing the cache, does it take 3 seconds for each run?

Comment: Hi stuartd, It is slowly every time. I use Stopwatch write to log & YSlow Addon on Firefox. It same result.

Comment: This is output log: 2013-09-19 09:03:01,973 [19] INFO  Use Appfabric to get Province in 4726 milliseconds.
2013-09-19 09:03:18,924 [19] INFO  Use Appfabric to get Province in 3885 milliseconds.
2013-09-19 09:03:21,893 [19] INFO  Use Appfabric to get Province in 4209 milliseconds.
2013-09-19 09:03:21,912 [19] INFO  Use Appfabric to get Province in 3805 milliseconds.

Comment: You could try a bit of logging - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921010%28v=azure.10%29.aspx

Comment: I create one region to test with 100 records get form database to appfabric cache. I try don't use foreach by this function         public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> GetObjectsInRegion(string region)
        {
            var cache = GetCache();
            return cache.GetObjectsInRegion(region).Select(p => p.Value);
        }

Comment: Thanks stuartd. But it still slow.